# Flex: Possible to run multiple instances of a Flex application, each in a different browser window?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

Does a Flex application (by default) enable a user to log in more than once, each time using a new browser window or tab, and not run into any shared memory problems? That is, since it's the same application, the variables cached in local RAM (might) use the same name(?). Does Flex have any issues like this?

Or, since each running application is in a separate browser, they are considered to run independently from each other?

Also, if I add BlazeDS into the mix, does it add any new problems in the above scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all running in their own memory space so you won't have any conflicts or anything.

Comment: +1; however I have to wonder if you have an app running in windows or tabs in the same browser; they could be potentially be sharing browser cookies, which could potentially link up to a server side session.  Depending on the implementation [of both server and client] that may cause oddities.  But, it is too hard to know based on the little info provided.